# Skipping spaces in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I'm trying to write a conditional statement where I can skip a specific space then start reading all the characters after it.

I was thinking to use `substring` but that wouldn't help because `substring` will only work if I know the exact number of characters I want to skip but in this case, I want to skip a specific space to read characters afterward.

For example:

```
String text = "ABC DEF W YZ" //number of characters before the spaces are unknown

String test = "A"

if ( test == "A") {
    return text (/*escape the first two space and return anything after that*/)
}
```

Comment: By "escape", do you mean "skip"?

Comment: yes, skipping spaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split your string on `" "` with `tokenize`, remove the first `N` elements from the returned array (where `N` is the number of spaces you want to ignore) and join what's left with `" "`.

Supposing your `N` is 2:

```
String text = "ABC DEF W YZ" //number of characters before the spaces are unknown

String test = "A"

if ( test == "A") {
    return text.tokenize(" ").drop(2).join(" ")
}
```

Comment: Many Thanks Frederico. I've never used drop and would be thankful if you know any useful online site where I can read more about it please. I want to play more with this drop option like reading characters before spaces instead of after and so one.

Comment: I'll tell you a secret: I never coded in groovy outside of EL in JSF pages, so I put toghether some stuff from around the web to answer your question. I took `drop` from [here](http://mrhaki.blogspot.it/2011/09/groovy-goodness-take-and-drop-items.html)